# What is the replacement for sun.security.tools.JarSigner (java 6) in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, jarsigner

I have an application that generates a jar file, and I need it to sign the jar file programmatically using java 8.

Comment: Did the class move or something? What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks @4castle,  yes, I just found that JarSigner is not a class anymore in java 8.  They move it to sun.security.tools.jarsigner.Main.  I'm now looking how to use it.